# GeometryReader still takes into account hidden navigation bar of hosting controller

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `UIHostingController` subclass that hides the navigation bar on `viewDidLoad`. Inside my hosting controller, I have a SwiftUI view that uses the geometry reader to calculate the top safe area inset. Unfortunately, I think the geometry reader still thinks the navigation bar is visible so reports the wrong top safe area inset size. How do I get it to report the correct inset? Here's my code:

```
final class NavigationHostingController<Content: View>: UIHostingController<Content> {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    }
}


struct AccountDetailsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Color.yellow
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .frame(height: geometry.safeAreaInsets.top)
                // some other views
           }
        }
    }
}

let viewController = NavigationHostingController(rootView: accountDetailsView)
navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: You need a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: How are you using `let viewController = NavigationHostingController(rootView: accountDetailsView)`
`navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)`?

Answer (score 0):

UIHostingController does not ignore safe area insets, which seems to be a bug. There is a way to hack around the problem by [swizzling](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2019/swizzling-in-swift/) the UIHostingController’s safe area methods so we can return insets of `.zero`:

```swift
final class NavigationHostingController<Content: View>: UIHostingController<Content> {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        disableSafeArea()
    }
    
    private func disableSafeArea() {
        guard let viewClass = object_getClass(view) else { return }
        
        let viewSubclassName = String(cString: class_getName(viewClass)).appending("_IgnoreSafeArea")
        if let viewSubclass = NSClassFromString(viewSubclassName) {
            object_setClass(view, viewSubclass)
        }
        else {
            guard let viewClassNameUtf8 = (viewSubclassName as NSString).utf8String else { return }
            guard let viewSubclass = objc_allocateClassPair(viewClass, viewClassNameUtf8, 0) else { return }
            
            if let method = class_getInstanceMethod(UIView.self, #selector(getter: UIView.safeAreaInsets)) {
                let safeAreaInsets: @convention(block) (AnyObject) -> UIEdgeInsets = { obj in
                    if var insets = (obj as? UIView)?.superview?.safeAreaInsets {
                        insets.top = 0
                        return insets
                    } else {
                        return .zero
                    }
                }
                class_addMethod(viewSubclass, #selector(getter: UIView.safeAreaInsets), imp_implementationWithBlock(safeAreaInsets), method_getTypeEncoding(method))
            }
            
            objc_registerClassPair(viewSubclass)
            object_setClass(view, viewSubclass)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One addendum: In my sample code, I call disableSafeArea() in viewDidLoad, but depending on your app it’s possible that viewDidLoad is “too late” and you’ll still see safe areas. If that happens, override init and call disableSafeArea there instead.